# Data Binding to DataGridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

Im using a `List<Patient>` object as the data source to a data grid view. I need to use concatenation of two string properties in the `Patient` class as the value of a single text box column.
I know this can be done by using the `OnRowDataBound` event in the webforms GridView. How to handle this situation in win forms? I cant see OnRowDataBound event in the win forms Data grid view.

For clarification my Patient class is,

```
public class Patient
{
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to bind the combination of these two properties to a single column called 'Name' in the grid view. And also there are some other properties in the `Patient` class which are directly mapped to the data grid view columns using the DataPropertyName of columns. So it is tedious to fill all the columns programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is adding a new property that computes the value to your (view) model and binding to this property.

```
public class Patient
{
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string InitialsAndLastName
    {
        get { return this.Initials + " " + this.LastName; }
    }
}
```